# AggregateRoot Class DDD Multiple entities

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, domain-driven-design, aggregate

I couldn't find a specific answer to my question but how would I develop an AggregateRoot class for the following scenario.

```
public class Root{

    public int Id {get;set;}
    public IList<Child> Children {get;set;}

}

public class Child{
    public int Id{get;set; }
    public IList<SubChild> SubChildren{get;set; }
}

public class SubChild{
    public int Id {get;set;}
}
```

How can the root class update the SubChild class following DDD principles?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking here.  If your goal is to simply follow the rules, then learn the rules.  Otherwise, find a sensible class structure, and work out how the classes are going to communicate with each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do violates the [Law of the Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter). `Subchildren` should be managed by `Child` only, not `Root` class.

You might think about this like your `Root` is an aggregate, `Child` - is a subaggregate.